# Calling Fragment Method giving null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I've been struggling for too long and now I gave up, Can anyone help?
So I have Fragment A attached with tab (ViewPager).
And then I have Fragment B which I'm replacing with Fragment A if user click on some buttons I've in Fragment A.
I'm using the below code to replace the fragment.

```
FragmentB fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance(mContext, conversationObj);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rlt_home_page_content, fragment, "Bro");
fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("frag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now, onDetach() of Fragment B, I'm calling Fragment A's method like this:

```
public void onDetach() {
    FragmentA fa = FragmentA.newInstance(mContext);
    fa.onResume();
}
```

And this is my onResume() code at FragmentA;

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//Toast.makeText(mContext, "onResume() Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So, The issue is, The Toast is showing but I'm getting following error;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on a null object reference
```

Please Help

**UPDATE**

I'm initializing my adapter in my Fragment A onCreateView() like:

```
adapter = new adapter(conversations, mContext, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also, I've tried to initialize my adapter in my onResume() method as well but still same error

Comment: Your adapter object is accessible in the onResume method, right? if not try to define it as a class member.

Comment: Well, I didn't understand Since I'm a noob, Can I get the code sample instead? Please

Comment: where you insert your adapter?

Comment: @MohsenEl_sayed In onCreateView

Comment: just remove it from there and declare like : `class Demofrag Extends Fragment{ YOUR_ADAPTER_CLASS_NAME adpater;`

Comment: So, Where would this line of code go?

Comment: in Fragment A or B?

Comment: it would be good if you can share your fragmentA code.

Comment: @Vaibhav_sorathiya yah i agree with you

Comment: I've added my Fragment A code as well in Question